# How do I remove the bash from systemd service file? and replace it with something that solves my problem explained below?

Tags: bash, systemd

Boring details alert:
I have a `systemd` `service` file which uses a bash file to start the service. Below is the service file in question:

```
[Unit]
Description=A program service
[Service]
User=root
#change this to your workspace
WorkingDirectory=/data/acloud/repository/lib
#path to executable. 
#executable is a bash script file I created to run the application jar file
ExecStart=/data/acloud/repository/lib/program.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Below is `program.sh` I used in the service file above:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g -Xms512m -jar abc-program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

If you are wondering why I created a single line bash script, its because I do not know where and how to put the *-XX, -Xms -Xmx* parameters in `.service` file.

Even when the service is inactive, Main PID status is shown as `status=0/SUCCESS` and at the end of the `systemctl status` command output, it says `Started a program service`?? Below is how its shown:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-**-**-***:/data/acloud/repository/lib$ sudo systemctl status program
program.service - A program service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/program.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2019-02-22 13:08:21 UTC; 45s ago
  Process: 27711 ExecStart=/data/acloud/repository/lib/program.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 27711 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 22 13:08:21 ip-172-**-**-*** systemd[1]: Started A program service.
```

I believe that using bash is causing this problem as the exit codes are not manipulated in here. How do I get this to stop?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54840001/7552

Answer (score 1):

## Remove sudo

sudo is almost always a mistake in systemd scripts.

- If the unit is a system unit its superfluous
- if its not sudo will fail most likely
- if its used for other purposes eg `-H` `-g` etc then systemd has all these functionalities

In short

```
$ sudo java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g -Xms512m -jar abc-program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

can be replaced by

```
$ java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g -Xms512m -jar abc-program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now moving it into the unit itself ie

## Remove the shell script

What prevents this from working?

```
ExecStart=java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g -Xms512m -jar abc-program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Maybe nothing (it just works!)

But its possible paths need adjusting. You already have

```
WorkingDirectory=/data/acloud/repository/lib
```

I recommend looking into https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html theres `User=` `Group=`

Is java on the path? You can tweak the PATH env variable but simplest to change to

```
ExecStart=/fullpath/to/java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g…
```

(Change fullpath as appropriate to you)

Does it still work? I suspect not…

## Correct Service type

So what happens if you run (at the shell) (Note NO `&` at end)

```
$ sudo java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g -Xms512m -jar abc-program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

1. If it does its job and comes out you need

   ```
   type=oneshot
   ```
2. If it keeps running in foreground (ie it 'hangs' until killed) you need

   ```
   type=simple
   ```
3. If it immediately returns with the daemon running in background you need

   ```
   type=forking
   ```

If its the third you also need to supply

```
PIDFile=/path/to/service/pidfile
```

If the first you need

```
RemainAfterExit=yes
```